# How to paint the unfilled part of the bar chart with a specific color? ChartJs/React-Chart-js

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, dataset

I have regular Bar chart. What I need is to paint unfilled parts of this chart with specific color, like on the screenshot bellow:

[fill chart screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI5I1.png)

Comment: Which chart library are you using? Can you provide some of your related code?

Comment: I think you can use the plugin stacked100: https://github.com/y-takey/chartjs-plugin-stacked100